# How to get parent id with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

```js
$('td').click(function() {
  myId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
  myItem = $(this).text();
  alert('u clicked ' + myId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Computer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>maths</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>physics</td></div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I click on table item I want to get alert `'u clicked science'` but I get `undefined`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try, alert('u clicked ' +myItem);

Comment: Why i do not see any `id`s in html?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the outer html - your current code does not show any id attributes or indeed the string `science` anywhere. I guess thats contained in a parenet element, but to answer i would need to see that element

Comment: @Rayon Dabre : why did you removed the markup OP added??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, Was approving edit of Rajesh. Apologies..

Comment: This question is currently unanswerable, voting to close as unclear

Answer (score 2):

> There are no `id` attributes in your `markup`. All you are dealing with is `innerText`

```js
$('td').click(function() {

  var myItem = $(this).text();
  alert('u clicked ' + myItem);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Computer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>maths</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>physics</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `"u clicked science"` strongly suggests there is a parent element not shown in the question. `science` does not appear in any of the text nodes, plus `computer, maths and physics` can all be loosely considered areas of science, but ultimately its anyone's guess unless the OP responds

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid markup. extra closing div is added after last tr closing markup. you need to remove it.

what you need to alert is text of element and not parent id. use `.text()` along with clicked td elements jquery context:

```js
$('td').click(function(){
 myItem=$(this).text();
 alert('u clicked ' +myItem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>


<tr><td>Computer</td></tr>


<tr><td>maths</td></tr>

<tr><td>physics</td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $('td').click(function () {
        alert('u clicked ' + $(this).text());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have already commented, you are missing `ID` in `tr`. I have added few more `td`s for demo.

```js
$('td').click(function() {
  var myId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
  var myItem = $(this).text();
  alert('u clicked ' + myId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="IT">
    <td>Computer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="General">
    <td>maths</td>
    <td>History</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Science">
    <td>physics</td>
    <td>Chemistry</td>
    <td>Biology</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```